# Deploying JS/CSS to hive w/o farm solution

Tags: deployment, hive

I’d have a question on provisioning files (CSS & JavaScript) into a custom folder inside the hive (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\custom).

We like to avoid using a farm solution for the sole purpose of copying new versions of the files into the above location; we are therefore thinking of an installation routine outside of SharePoint to do the copying of those files instead of a farm solution. This routine would be run by an administrator directly on the front end server.

Would there be any major concerns about this approach? Is there anything we should be wary of?